# asp.net mvc enable on delete cascade for entire project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've searched for something that solves my problem, but don't seem to find anything.

Is there a way to simply enable OnDeleteCascade for the entire project?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You database or code first?

Comment: @DavidLee code first.

Comment: Setup Cascade delete on your ModelBuilder

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Posted an answer that should get you started.  The resource I linked should help you with the various relationship types.

Comment: I really don't think enabling cascade delete for the whole project is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to setup your relationships in your DbContext and specify your cascade deletes in your model builder.

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EntityOne> EntityOnes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EntityTwo> EntityTwos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityOne>()
            .HasRequired(d => d.EntityTwo)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true); // this is what you want to do
    }
}
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Reference (This one is really good for various relationships): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx

EDIT: Wanted to note this is called **Entity Framework Fluent API** if you wanted to google for some more info.