# Many to Many Relationship with extra columns in EF 6 Code?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Say if I have the classic example of Student and Courses. A student can have many courses and course can have many students.

How do I make the middle table in EF 6 code if I wanted to add an extra field on the many table part?

Do I just make in code another class and then hook it up somehow?

DB Context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext (string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        // this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<OSPContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public DbSet<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }

}


public class StudentCourse
{
    [Key]
    public Guid StudentCourseId { get; set; }

    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; } // Include this so you can access it later

    public Guid CourseId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

    public int Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public  Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; } = new >();
}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public  Guid Id { get; set; }
    public  string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } = new List<Course>();

}
```

Comment: Code first or database first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given you are code first I would do something like the following.

```
public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<StudentCourse> Courses { get; set; } // So you can access Courses for a student
}

public class Course
{
    [Key]
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<StudentCourse> Students { get; set; }
}

public class StudentCourse
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentCourseId { get; set; }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StudentId")]
    public Student Student { get; set; } // Include this so you can access it later

    public int CourseId { get; set; }        
    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public Course Course { get; set; } 
}
```

EDIT: Wanted to note relationships are established with Data Attributes, you could also use EF Fluent API to establish your relationships.  The properties will look the same, but without the `[ForeignKey("")]`

Comment: Ok, I will have to look up how to do Fluent API.

Comment: @chobo2 Take a look at my answer here about cascade deletes as it uses Fluent API.  There are also two links to very useful references. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787339/asp-net-mvc-enable-on-delete-cascade-for-entire-project/44787466#44787466

Comment: Do I add StudentCourse to my context? Right now I am just copied what you have but the StudentCourse is not being created correctly(I added another property and it does not show up)

Comment: Yes, you will need to add StudentCourse to your DbContext

Comment: In addition if you are code first you will need to run a migration in order to update your database with any changes to your models.

Comment: Hmm, I did that but I get now 2 many tables. One called StudentCourse1 and one StudentCourse. One has my new column keys, and one just has the relationship key. See my OP for code

Comment: Have you tried deleting your database and recreating it?

Comment: Yes, it gets recreated every time. I think it might be something with the ids maybe. You have like CourseId in your Course class where I just have "Id".

Comment: The `[Key]` Data Attribute should prevent any naming convention issues on the Id.

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but in your `Student` and `Course` models you need to have the lists go to the `StudentCourse`

Comment: Yes that was the issue.